# Sass excluding application.css file for a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass

I just upgraded my project from Rails 3.0.7 to 3.1.0 and I see that I can use SASS now.

I have a page in my application which is just a promotional page at `/home/subscribe.html.erb` and I would like it to not inherit the css declarations being used throughout the application like the scaffold.css. There is a separate subscribe.css file which I would like it to inherit ONLY.

Even though I have gone inside my application.css.scss and changed it to have only: `@import "scaffold.css.scss";` the application.css.scss still gets inherited as a part of the application in to the subscribe page.

can you please suggest how to make the subscribe page ONLY use the subscribe.css file and no other css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new layout that has a css tag that directly targets the css file you wish to import rather than application.css.

Comment: how will i tell rails that the susbscibe.html.erb is to use that new layout file I will create in the layout folder?

Comment: You can add `layout :subscribe` to the controller method. (This is all in the docs by the way.)